# adb send keystroke doesn't work

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to emulate input from my android application to make some test.

Well, my Android phone (AREO 8.1.0) is connected to USB and my debugger is enabled.

I use some

```
 adb shell input tap 90 310
 adb shell input text "banana"
```

and my keyboard open as well with "banana" text in the text field (keyboard and apps textfield)

The problem is the next step:

```
adb shell input keyevent 66 # ENTER input
```

It won't send this command.

I'm thinking its about my custom keyboard.

I use

[image: adb shell cat /......./Generic.kl]

to find whats the keyevent I need.

I also use the

```
keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER
keyevent KEYCODE_TAB
...
```

[image: many command in console with ADB]

the keyevent `BACK, SPACE, CLEAR` works as well but not the `ENTER`

*by the way, I tried with and without `--longpress`

Anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: What is your custom keyboard?

Comment: swiftKey keyboard but I tried with Gboard too and its the same issue